# List item with double quotes

Tags: java, android, string, list, arraylist

I want list item should be with double quotes.
i tried like this :

```
List<String> langList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Language obj : language) {
        langList.add(obj.getCode());
    }
JSONObject where = new JSONObject();
try {
    JSONObject languages = new JSONObject();
    languages.put("$in", langList);
    where.put("languages", languages);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

result of `langList` is : `"[en, ta, hi]"`
and I added double quotes for items using `langList.add("\"" + obj.getCode() + "\"");`

now, It returns the result is : `"[\"en\", \"ta\", \"hi\"]"`

I don't want outside double quotes also.

am expecting result is : `["en", "ta", "hi"]`

Comment: How do you output the list?

Comment: How is the language list formatted?

Comment: after putting `langList` to JSONObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added an extra " to both sides before adding them to the list. PFB the code snippet.

```
String array[] = new String[] {"en","ta", "hi"};
List<String> langList = new ArrayList<>();
for (String item : array) {
    langList.add("\""+item+"\"");
}

System.out.println("langList: "+ langList);

try {
    JSONArray jsonObject = new JSONArray(langList.toString());
    System.out.println("jsonObject: "+jsonObject);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I could see below logs in console.

```
langList: ["en", "ta", "hi"]
jsonObject: ["en","ta","hi"]
```

Hope this helps.

Note: Used `org.json.JSONArray` and `org.json.JSONException` classes in above code.

Comment: Happy to hear it was of help

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use:

```
langList.add('"' + obj.getCode() + '"');
```

Comment: sorry,just tested it my side,it will compile when use `+`

Comment: @lucumt no issue.

Comment: I tried this way also but same result `"[\"en\", \"ta\", \"hi\"]"`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
List<String> langList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Language obj : language) {
    langList.add('"'+obj.getCode()+'"');
}
```

Comment: I tried this way also but same result `"[\"en\", \"ta\", \"hi\"]"`

Comment: how are you checking the data inside `langList`

Comment: After put list into `JSONObject`. so that object showing like that... I updated the question pls check

Answer (score -1):

Add double quotes for items using this:

```
    List<String> langList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Language obj : language) {
        langList.add('"'+obj.getCode()+'"');
    }
```